# kafka connect job that was working in version 0.9 not working in 0.10.2

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, data-ingestion

When i run my kafka connect job, i get the error below

```
[2017-04-25 14:56:22,806] ERROR Failed to create job for ./etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/sqlserver.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:88)
[2017-04-25 14:56:22,808] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:99)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector configuration is invalid (use the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate` to get a full list of errors)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:80)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:67)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:96)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: 
Connector configuration is invalid (use the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate` to get a full list of errors)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.putConnectorConfig(StandaloneHerder.java:161)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:93)
```

My properties file is

```
name=test-sqlserver-jdbc-autoincrement
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.9.142:1433;databaseName=postilion;user=elasticsearch;password=elasticsearch
query=select convert(varchar(10), date_time, 120) as date,convert(char(12), 
date_time, 114) as time, * from support_notifications
mode=timestamp+incrementing
timestamp.column.name=date_time
incrementing.column.name=event_nr
topic.prefix=test-events
```

I've tried to do a **GET** call to kafka connect(Before it crashes) using `curl http://localhost:8083 /JdbcSourceConnector/config/validate` and i get the response `{"version":"0.10.2.0-cp1","commit":"64c9b42f3319cdc9"}curl: (3) <url> malformed`. Any ideas what i'm doing wrong as this job worked in kafka 0.9.

Comment: Kafka 0.10.2.0 had a bug regarding the configuration validation where it didn't report the real issues... We released 0.10.2.1 yesterday, which should fix this (and 28 other bugs). Give it a try.

Comment: @Zigmaphi You go the response  `curl http://localhost:8083 /JdbcSourceConnector/config/validate` because you had a space between "8083" and "/JdbcSourceConnector"  in your request. You should have gotten a response similar to ` {
    "error_code": 400,
    "message": "Connector config {} contains no connector type"
}`

Answer (score 0):

So i found a way out. I ended up altering the **mode** from **timestamp+incrementing** to **incrementing** in the properties file and removed the line **timestamp.column.name=date_time**. The properties file now looks like this

```
name=test-sqlserver-jdbc-autoincrement
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.9.142:1433;databaseName=postilion;user=elasticsearch;password=elasticsearch
query=select convert(varchar(10), date_time, 120) as date,convert(char(12), date_time, 114) as time, * from support_notifications
mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=event_nr
topic.prefix=postilion-events
```